# Laravel routing fails beyond home page

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, bootstrapping

I am having issues on my Hostmonster shared hosting site with routing pages beyond the homepage. I am using starter site code with the Laravel framework from here:

https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site

The home works fine however beyond this I am having issues. When I try to login in I get the following error when my url tries to access `http://example.com/user/login` . How do I fix this issue so that my pages route to the proper place OR How do I fix this issue? Thank you.

Error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /public/user/login was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at example.com Port 80
```

In my .htaccess file I have

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

#AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php


RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]
```

In my routes I have this

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route model binding
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::model('comment', 'Comment');
Route::model('post', 'Post');
Route::model('role', 'Role');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route constraint patterns
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::pattern('comment', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('post', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('user', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('role', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('token', '[0-9a-z]+');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Admin Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{

    # Comment Management
    Route::get('comments/{comment}/edit', 'AdminCommentsController@getEdit');
    Route::post('comments/{comment}/edit', 'AdminCommentsController@postEdit');
    Route::get('comments/{comment}/delete', 'AdminCommentsController@getDelete');
    Route::post('comments/{comment}/delete', 'AdminCommentsController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('comments', 'AdminCommentsController');

    # Blog Management
    Route::get('blogs/{post}/show', 'AdminBlogsController@getShow');
    Route::get('blogs/{post}/edit', 'AdminBlogsController@getEdit');
    Route::post('blogs/{post}/edit', 'AdminBlogsController@postEdit');
    Route::get('blogs/{post}/delete', 'AdminBlogsController@getDelete');
    Route::post('blogs/{post}/delete', 'AdminBlogsController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('blogs', 'AdminBlogsController');

    # User Management
    Route::get('users/{user}/show', 'AdminUsersController@getShow');
    Route::get('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@getEdit');
    Route::post('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@postEdit');
    Route::get('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@getDelete');
    Route::post('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('users', 'AdminUsersController');

    # User Role Management
    Route::get('roles/{role}/show', 'AdminRolesController@getShow');
    Route::get('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@getEdit');
    Route::post('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@postEdit');
    Route::get('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@getDelete');
    Route::post('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('roles', 'AdminRolesController');

    # Admin Dashboard
    Route::controller('/', 'AdminDashboardController');
});


/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Frontend Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */

// User reset routes
Route::get('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@getReset');
// User password reset
Route::post('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@postReset');
//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/{user}/edit', 'UserController@postEdit');

//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@postLogin');

# User RESTful Routes (Login, Logout, Register, etc)
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');

//:: Application Routes ::

# Filter for detect language
Route::when('contact-us','detectLang');

# Contact Us Static Page
Route::get('contact-us', function()
{
    // Return about us page
    return View::make('site/contact-us');
});

# Posts - Second to last set, match slug
Route::get('{postSlug}', 'BlogController@getView');
Route::post('{postSlug}', 'BlogController@postView');

# Index Page - Last route, no matches
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'detectLang','uses' => 'BlogController@getIndex'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you activate the URL rewriting in your server config? on your **httpd.conf** file, you have to remove the '**#**' at the beginning of this 2 lines:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
AddModule mod_rewrite.c
```

To be sure it's activated or not, you can check **phpinfo()** and look for **mod_rewrite**.

Comment: I don't think I have access to that file on my shared hosting site. Anyway around this?

Comment: well at least try to upload a simple file like info.php with one line phpinfo(), so you will be sure or not. It MUST be activated for working, as documentation said http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this documentation. It helped me figure out the problem. The .htaccess file I had was in my root directory / but I also needed a .htaccess file in the /public directory.